# How to send std::string array between processes C++

Tags: c++, system, ipc, pipe

In C++, I need to start a secondary program from a primary program, sending the second some arguments. I need to return the data produced by the secondary program to the primary program. In this case, the data happens to be a two-dimensional std::string array; we'll call it `stringArray`. This is easy enough to do:

```
// snippet from Primary
std::string executionString ("./secondaryProgram arg1 arg2 arg3");
system(executionString);
```

What I don't know how to do is get the data that Secondary Program produces back to the Primary program (short of writing to a temporary file from Secondary and then reading the file from Primary).

In other words, it would be great if I could do something like:

```
// snippet from Primary
std::string stringArray[2][3];  
stringArray = system(executionString);
```

I'm not hoping for a solution as simple as this or working code from anyone, any nudge in the right direction is appreciated.

I cannot use sockets for this purpose. I have not been able to figure out how to build a pipe between std::cout and std::cin that works for this case. My only real constraint is that my solution involve `system()` somehow.

Comment: "I cannot use sockets for this purpose." Why?

Comment: why must your solution involve `system`?

Comment: There is something wrong about this question. "How to send ... through *sockets*?" + "I *cannot use sockets*" + "my solution [has to] involve `system()`" = `?`

Comment: @leemes, thank you. I honestly don't remember writing that, but I guess I must have. Edited title.

Comment: No problem. Thought that ;) Does the professor think that reading and writing to the child process' stdin / stdout has to be done using `system()`?

Comment: @leemes, well he first told us to use `exec()` but the next class was like "Well, that executes an external program and never returns control to the original. Use `system()` instead". All the piping examples I see on the Internet use `pipe()` and `fork()`, etc. I don't suppose I <i>have</i> to use `system()`. Is there no known way to return data from a `system(program)` call? I'm not really a native C++ speaker, so this is giving me a bit of trouble.

Comment: Alternatively, use `popen`. `system()` won't access you the output or input stream, I think. Please also keep in mind that *all* of those functions are pure C. In C++ under windows you also have [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) if `popen` isn't available (have a look at `_popen`, it should be the same as `popen`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright here's what I ended up doing.

"translate"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>

std::vector<std::string> sortTerms(int n, char* argv[]) {
  std::vector<std::string> sortedTerms (n);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
sortedTerms[i] = argv[i+1]; // first term argv is program name
  }

  std::sort(sortedTerms.begin(),sortedTerms.end());

  return sortedTerms;
}

std::vector<std::string> splitString(int n,std::string str) {
  std::vector<std::string> stringVector (n);

  std::istringstream iss(str);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
std::getline(iss, stringVector[i], ' ');

  return stringVector;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  const int NUM_TERMS = (argc - 1); // number of words to translate
  std::string output[NUM_TERMS][2]; // used to store a translated word alongside the English equivalent
  std::string stringBuffer; // used to start dictionary with arguments
  std::vector<std::string> stringVector (NUM_TERMS); // used as a buffer
  std::ofstream outputFile("translated.txt"); // file to write translations to
  const bool VERBOSE = true;

  stringBuffer.clear();
  stringBuffer.append("./dictionary ");

  // Sort English words and load them into output
  stringVector = sortTerms(NUM_TERMS, argv);
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TERMS; i++) {
output[i][0] = stringVector[i];
stringBuffer = stringBuffer.append(stringVector[i]);
stringBuffer = stringBuffer.append(" ");
  }

  int pipeStatus;
  int pipeOutput[2]; // file descriptor

  pipeStatus = pipe(pipeOutput); // create output read/write pipe ends
  if (pipeStatus < 0) {
std::cerr << "ERROR CREATING PIPE" << std::endl;
exit(1);
  }

  int pid = 0;
  pid = fork();

  if (pid == 0) { // dictionary
// Connect the pipes
dup2 (pipeOutput[1],1);

// Execute the program
system(stringBuffer.c_str());

// Close pipes
close(pipeOutput[0]);
close(pipeOutput[1]);

exit(0);
  }
  else if (pid > 0) { // Original process
char* buffer = new char[1024]; // input buffer

// Receive string from dictionary
read(pipeOutput[0],buffer,1024); // read in from output of dictionary

stringBuffer = buffer; // I'd rather work with a std::string

stringVector = splitString(NUM_TERMS, stringBuffer);
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TERMS; i++)
  output[i][1] = stringVector[i];

// Close pipes
close(pipeOutput[0]);
close(pipeOutput[1]);

if (VERBOSE) {
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TERMS; i++)
    std::cout << output[i][0] << " -> " << output[i][1] << std::endl;
}

// write translationString to file
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TERMS; i++) {
  outputFile.write(output[i][0].c_str(),output[i][0].length());
  outputFile.write(" -> ",4);
  outputFile.write(output[i][1].c_str(),output[i][1].length());
  outputFile.write("\n",1);
} 

outputFile.close();

exit(0);
  }
  else if (pid == -1) {
std::cerr << "ERROR FORKING PROCESS" << std::endl;
exit(1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

"dictionary"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> splitString(std::string str)
{
  std::vector<std::string> stringVector (2);

  std::istringstream iss(str);

  std::getline(iss, stringVector[0], ' ');
  std::getline(iss, stringVector[1], ' ');

  return stringVector;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {  
  const int NUM_TERMS = (argc - 1);
  std::string stringBuffer;
  std::string returnString[NUM_TERMS];
  std::vector<std::string> stringVector;
  std::ifstream dictionaryFile ("./dictionary.txt");

  // There must be at least one arguement
  if (argc <= 1)
std::cout << "Nothing to translate..." << std::endl;

  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TERMS; i++) {
while (dictionaryFile) {
  getline(dictionaryFile,stringBuffer);  
  stringVector = splitString(stringBuffer);
  if (stringVector[0] == argv[i+1]) { // wut
    returnString[i] = stringVector[1];
    break;
  }
}
  }

  // clear string buffer
  stringBuffer.clear();

  // Form translated words string
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TERMS; i++) {
    stringBuffer.append(returnString[i]);
    if (i < (NUM_TERMS - 1))
        stringBuffer.append(" "); // append a space after each but the last term
  }

  // print translated words
  std::cout << stringBuffer << std::endl;

  dictionaryFile.close();

  return 0;
}
```

"dictionary.txt"

```
Apple Apfel
Banana Banane
Blackberry Brombeere
Blueberry Heidelbeere
Cherry Kirsche
Fruit Obst
Grape Traube
Lemon Zitrone
Lime Limone
Orange Orange
Peach Pfirsich
Pear Birne
Plum Zwetschge
Raspberry Himbeere
Strawberry Erdbeere
```

meant to be run like `$ ./dictionary Apple Orange Strawberry`

produces "translated.txt"

```
Apple -> Apfel
Orange -> Orange
Strawberry -> Erdbeere
```

I've still got a bit of polishing to do before I turn it in, but that's the gist of it. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

`system()` does not create pipes to the child process. The child process inherits the parent's standard in, standard out, and standard error descriptors.

On Linux, you can use `popen()` if you want access to the child's stdin or stdout.

Since you have to use `system()`, you could 
have the secondary program store its results in a file. Your main program would then open the file after the system completes. Sort of like this:

```
std::string executionString ("./secondaryProgram arg1 arg2 arg3 > output_file.txt");
system(executionString);
std::ifstream result("output_file.txt");
while( result >> str) {
  result_vector.push_back(str);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `system` supports shell syntax?

Comment: He specifically said he wasn't looking for this solution.

Comment: @JonBentley He specifically said that he *has to use* `system()`

Comment: @leemes - yes. The string is handed to `sh -c`.

Comment: I mentioned this solution and implied that it would not be a satisfactory solution in my OP (which I admit might have been TL;DR). I need to send the information directly from one process to the other. It's OK if I have to break my std::string array into something more primitive, I'd just like the simplicity of being able to send one piece of data and be done with it.

Comment: @Alex - sorry, I missed your mention of this solution. Good luck finding an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [boost.interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/interprocess.html). It contains many utilities that can be used for IPC in a portable way.

If you don't want to rely on boost, you can do something like [this](http://ideone.com/8BHdm6). Compile with C++11 mode and `-pthread` GCC option.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write the relevant information in the second process to a file, and then read that file in the first process. Seems weird to do it this way, but I think it meets your professor's criteria, at least the parts you've shared with us.

Answer (score 0):

[Boost Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) should work for you. It supports message queues between threads on different processes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pipes](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipes-and-FIFOs.html) to communicate. The link provided has examples for linux, but it's very similar to what you would write for windows.

If you need to send arbitrary data that might change at run time you might consider serializing the data sent over the pipes and deserializing it at the receiver. You might use XML, JSON, or something like [Protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/). If you make it human readable that adds the opportunity to reuse components or debug what's happening using the [eyeball mark 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_inspection)